# Using Loops in Python Newton-Raphson Algorithm for NPV and IRR

Tags: python, function, numpy, loops, finance

I would like to create a function called 'npv_zero'.
Its input arguments should be a cashflow vector and a start value. Its output argument should be a zero of NPV(r). I would like to include Newton-Raphson method to calculate the zero of the function NPV(x)=C1+2C2*x+3C3*x**2+...

with the explicit derivative. Finally I would like to re-transform x and obtain the IRR(internal rate of return). To sum up I would like to use iteration steps k=10 and tolerance eps=10**-5.

I tried this code, but it does not include these two input arguments, I don't know how to create Newton-Raphson with a vector, that is why I created these separate values C0, C1, C2, C3..

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

# Defining variables for Newton Raphson Calculation
CO = -100 # Cashflow in t=0
C1 = 10 # Cashflow in t=1
C2 = 20 # Cashflow in t=2
C3 = 60 # Cashflow in t=3
x = 0.88 # the inital guess

# Newton Raphson function
def npv_zero(fn, x, tol = 0.00000000001, maxiter = 100):
    for i in range(maxiter):
        x_new = x - fn[0](x)/fn[1](x)
        if abs(x_new - x) < tol: break
        x = x_new
    return x_new, i

y = [lambda x: CO + C1*x + C2*x**2 + C3*x**3, # f(x)
     lambda x: C1 + 2*C1*x + 3*C3*x**2] # f'(x)
x, n = npv_zero(y, 0.88)
print('the root is %f at %d iterations.' % (x,n))
```

Result: the root is 1.041930 at 11 iterations.
Next the IRR-Calculation:

```
# IRR-Calculation
def irr(x):
    """
    Function to calculate the IRR of a project
    Parameter
    ---------
    x (numpy array): cashflow vector
    Returns
    -------
    float: IRR
    """
    t = np.arange(len(x))
    npv = lambda r: x @ (1 / (1+r)) ** t
    return fsolve(npv, 0)

cashflow = [CO, C1, C2, C3]
print(irr(cashflow))
print(np.npv(0.11397637333244609, cashflow))
```

Result: -0.04024282, -31.503021914119515

Feel free to write a comment below!
Greetings:)

Comment: Hi, thanks for inviting me to write a comment. My comment is: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have another comment: The code you have shown isn't indented correctly.

Comment: hello mkrieger1, my question is how can I improve my actual code by using a cashflow vector instead of variables. Its an exercise in my current studies.. sorry for any circumstances I wrote. it is my first time asking a question

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, although I've not checked why it converges faster. I suspect your lambda functions are faster, however it seemed like fun to process the fn and fn' procedurally.

BTW, your indentation in your question is certainly awful. Took me some messing around to work out what you actually intended.

```
# Defining variables for Newton Raphson Calculation
CO = -100  # Cashflow in t=0
C1 = 10  # Cashflow in t=1
C2 = 20  # Cashflow in t=2
C3 = 60  # Cashflow in t=3
x = 0.88  # the inital guess


def npv_zero(coeff_vector, x, tol=0.00000000001, maxiter=100):
    """Newton Raphson function."""
    def fn(x):
        return sum(c*x**i for i, c in enumerate(coeff_vector))

    def fn_(x):
        return sum((i+1)*c*x**i for i, c in enumerate(coeff_vector[1:]))

    for _i in range(maxiter):
        x_new = x - fn(x) / fn_(x)
        if abs(x_new - x) < tol:
            break
        x = x_new
    return x_new, _i


x, n = npv_zero([CO, C1, C2, C3], 0.88)
print('the root is %f at %d iterations.' % (x, n))
```

Comment: hi jwal, sorry for my awful question.. But this seems to be quite nice! Big thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Joneslu not an awful question. In Python its just _really_ important to be precise about indentation.

Answer (score 0):

To use `np.arrays` in the code the array of cashflows can be multiplied by an array of discount factors.  The `d_npv` function uses the same array of discount factors set back one index and the cashflows are multiplied (once) by `np.arange`:

```
sum( [ c0, c1, c2, c3 ] * [ 1, x, x**2, x**3 ] ) => npv
sum( [ c0*0, c1*1, c2*2, c3*3 ] * [ 1, 1, x, x**2 ] ) => d_npv
```

This is implemented in `funcs()` below.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

CO = -100 # Cashflow in t=0
C1 = 10 # Cashflow in t=1
C2 = 20 # Cashflow in t=2
C3 = 60 # Cashflow in t=3
x = 0.88 # the inital guess

def funcs( cashflow ):
    """  Return npv and npv' functions for cashflow.
         cashflow is an np.array. 
    """
    gradient_coeffs = cashflow * np.arange( len(cashflow) )
    discount_factors = np.ones( len(cashflow) + 1 )
    # Recalculated for each run of npv for x.

    # discount_factors = [ 1, 1, x, x**2, x**3 ]
    # for npv calc          [ 1, x, x**2, x**3 ] ;  discount_factors[ 1: ]
    # fpr d_npv calc     [ 1, 1, x, x**2 ]       ;  discount_factors[ : -1 ]

    def npv( x ):
        """ npv calculation: assumes the first cashflow takes place at t = 0.
            i.e the discount factor for t=0 is 1.
        """
        nonlocal discount_factors
        discount_factors[ 2: ] = x
        discount_factors = discount_factors.cumprod()
        return np.array( [(cashflow * discount_factors[1:]).sum()] )

    def d_npv( x ):
        return np.array( [ ( gradient_coeffs * discount_factors[ : -1 ]).sum() ] )

    return npv, d_npv

func, fprime  = funcs( cashflow ) 

print( "Using fsolve: ", fsolve( func, x, fprime = fprime ) )
# Using fsolve:  [1.04193021]

# Newton Raphson function
fs = list( funcs( cashflow ) )
def npv_zero(fn, x, tol = 0.00000000001, maxiter = 100 ):
    for i in range(maxiter):
        x_new = x - fn[0](x)/fn[1](x)
        if abs(x_new - x) < tol: break
        x = x_new
    return x_new, i

print( "Using npv_zero: ", npv_zero( fs, x ) )
# Using npv_zero:  (array([1.04193021]), 4)
```

Comment: Hey Chris this looks fancy too! Thank you for your comment. Wish you a nice week :)